# Neural Network Setup and Monitoring in Reinforcement Learning

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I have a few questions about training a neural network using reinforcement learning, for example, DQN:
1. Should we use regularizers or dropouts when defining our model?
2. What we can monitor during the learning phase?

Answer (score 1):

1. There isn't really a universal answer to this question. It really depends on your environment and your approach and best thing to to do would be to test with and without and to compare results.
2. You could always start by monitoring your network loss and some environment performance metric per episode (if your environment is some game, you can monitor your score per episode)

Comment: First of all, thank you for attention. How about regularization? nearly every example I have seen so far have used NN without regularizations and dropouts. I was curious if it had a particular reason

Comment: The reason might be that agent usually has unlimited access to the environment and it potentially has 'unlimited' data - so we don't have to worry about overfitting. I don't feel like answering your question in detail - but please have a look at this answer https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/8295